# Where could the ASP home page be set?

Tags: asp.net

I have just taken over a new ASP VB website and I am having trouble finding whre the home page is set.

It has been a couple years since I worked with ASP.

I can find nothing in the following files:

```
web.config
global.asax
applicationHost.config
```

Nor do any of the following files exist:

```
Default.htm
Default.asp
index.htm
index.html
iisstart.htm
default.aspx
```

It is a web site project that I am dealing with.

I feel am missing something simple and stupid.

Thanks!

Comment: check your iis settings.

Comment: The mmc -> Microsoft Management Console

Comment: what's the version of IIS?

Comment: I believe it is IIS 7.0

Comment: It ended up being 7.5, thanks for all the helpful suggestions!

Comment: I am curious, why would anybody vote this question 'down?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IIS 7:

```
Administrative Tools-> IIS Manager -> You Server Name -> Your site name -> Under HTTP features -> Default document -> Add YourPage.aspx
```

Note: Change `YourPage.aspx` to whichever file you want to be the start/default page.

Comment: Turned out to be IIS 7.5 and this led me there. Thanks!

Comment: Follow-up question: Do you know where this information is stored?

Comment: @AbbyNormal - it is stored in web.config in an element called `<defaultDocument>`. Here is some documentation for [Default Document <defaultDocument>](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/defaultdocument).

Answer (score 0):

This may not necessarily be set anywhere in the app.  You can check IIS (assuming you have access to it) but the easiest way may be to open up the application in your web browser (in this example, I'm using Internet Explorer) and right click on the page.  Select "Properties" in the context menu.  This will display the address (URL) of the current page.  Note, though, that if your page consists of frames, you will see the address for the frame you targeted.  If this does not work, let me know and I'll send details on how to check IIS.